# Is hystrix with circuit breaker good for call forwarding and high TPS case?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I have three services A, B, and C. A receives calls from two sources, and forwards most calls to B service, some to C, and handles a few based on URIs. Before forwarding calls to B or C, A does a little trivial work. The peak requests per second handled by service A is about 60. Out of 60, 55 API calls are transferred to service B. We know two to three high frequency APIs of service B. Please note that all calls are synchronous in nature.

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1 and Spring Cloud Camden.RELEASE. As per my experiments using JMeter on local Windows machine, I see services are able to handle the expected requests per second. Once I make the service A as circuit breaker and wrap the high frequency API calls with **@HystrixCommand**, I see performance becomes poorer than what was before. Many API calls are failing by hystrix and fallbacks are called. Then upon increasing **execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds** command property value to "30000" and **coreSize** thread pool property value to "50", all calls have passed. I have observed that with hystrix stuff enabled, service A needs ~50 threads more than before. With more load, API execution time becomes higher and hence have increased the timeout property value.

Wondering

1. if making the service A as circuit breaker and wrapping the high
   frequency calls (or all calls) to service B inside service A with
   hystrix command are good decisions
2. if yes, is it not bad to change/increase thread counts manually
   through configuration in hystrix pool based on more TPS need in
   future? Without hystrix the situation is simple as spring boot
   automatically handles thread pools for serving load
3. As I need to modify the timeout property, now when the service B is
   stopped, A or hystrix takes some seconds to detect the service B is
   unreachable. The real advantage of using hystrix to stop cascading
   exhaust or stop service is not much. Still hystrix recommended?
4. Netflix recommends core size to be 10 default mostly and they have
   used till 25, not beyond. In my case, the need is 50

Your suggestions will be helpful here, especially to know if hystrix with circuit breaker is useful in my case, or how we can make it useful, or where else it is more suitable (where TPS to any service is low).

Comment: What do you mean "spring boot automatically handles thread pools for serving load"? Unless you are doing something else, calls from service A to B or C are on the main thread. See this comment from the Hystrix lead about how sizing threadpools https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1286#issuecomment-234633744

Answer (score 0):

Base on the [config doc](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#execution.isolation.strategy):

> Generally the only time you should use semaphore isolation (SEMAPHORE) is when the call is so high volume (hundreds per second, per instance) that the overhead of separate threads is too high;